# Parallelism: load an odd-element kernel to vector for Convolution

Tags: image, parallel-processing, kernel, convolution

Supposed that I have a very small and odd elements kernel (3x3) (stored in 1D array), I would like to use SSE to load that kernel into vectors and do the parallelism.

float *A;

If i'm doing like:

> _mm128 a1 = (A + 0)
>
> _mm128 a2 = (A + 4)
>
> _mm128 a3 = (A + 8)

Then it would be out of bound. Also, parallelism requires 4 vectors to best optimize the result.

What is the best way to load the small (odd-element) kernel into vector in order to use SSE?

Thank you.

Comment: Instead of loading the kernel into an SSE register you can load the array it's operating on.  Then you broadcast each kernel element and operate on 4 (8 with AVX) elements/pixels at once.  That way it does not matter what the size of the kernel is.

Comment: Is the Kernel separable, e.g. is it a Gaussian kernel?